# Get index of first dot with letter in a string

Tags: php, regex

I have a string like this one:

dsl-34.345.324-24718.pool.vodafone9.com (not a real hostname, just an example)

I've already tinkered around with preg_split which didn't gave me the good result.

Anyway, I'd like to get this result:

> pool.vodafone9.com

**EDIT**

Sorry, for not showing directly what I did with `preg_split()`, I already thought about doing that, however, it would have resulted into a completely wrong result when there are numbers within the domain.

```
preg_split( "/[0-9]\.[a-z]/", $hostAddr)
```

put out

> ools.vodafone.com

but with vodafone9.com it would have resulted in

> om

Comment: Please don't just ask us to solve the problem for you. Show us how you tried to solve the problem yourself, then show us exactly what the result was, and tell us why you feel it didn't work. Give us a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: Try posting what you tried with `preg_split` to show us what you've already done.

Comment: I've just edited my post  & thanks again zeterain :)

Comment: A fundamental problem with this question is that you say "like this one", but do not explain what "like" means. You want the result `"pool.vodafone9.com"` but do not you have not told us the *rule* you use to identify that part of the string. The rule could be, for example, "match from the first letter in the string that is preceded by a period that is preceded by a digit, to the end of the string". This is the problem of framing a question in terms of a single example. Such questions are almost always ambiguous.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try using this regular expression to detect everything after the first `.` followed by a single letter:

```php
$hostname = 'dsl-34.345.324-24718.pool.vodafone9.com';
$matches = array();
preg_match('/(?<=\.)[a-zA-Z].+/', $hostname, $matches);
echo $matches[0];
```